# How give the same permission of user folder to my hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I have two hard drivers, `C:\` , which is responsible by my OS (Windows 7) and another one, `D:\`, which is resposible by my all data, like photos, music, video, etc.
I would like to give permission to my folders located in D: as the same wich is given to `C:\Users\Valter\Music`.

Instead I store my music in `C:\Users\Valter\Music` I store in `D:\Music`. But both should have the same permission.

I'm asking that because a lot of software could not read my music files because of this permission thing.

**UPDATE**
Here it's in my `C:\Users\Valter\Imagens`

[image: C]

Here it's in my `D:\Images`

[image: D]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving your User/Music folder?

You can change the location of your folders like Documents, Music, Pictures, Downloads...

Just navigate to your User's folder (C:\Users\ on Windows 7) -> right-click on chosen folder -> Location -> Move -> Choose new location (in your case - folder on another drive). It will probably move the access properties as well.

But if it didn't, you can just edit permissions manually:
right-click on your Music folder ->
Security ->
Edit -> 
and here you can add/delete users and their permissions.

Comment: I'm gonna try to move the location and see what is done

Comment: still not working dude..

Comment: Are you under administrator's account? Have you tried to edit permissions manually?

Comment: yeah, I update my post where you can see it how it is my permissions.